# Java generate Artifacte failed

Tags: java

I know thats a quite simple question, but my problem is, that all my workarounds I've found don't work.

So a got a new Linux Computer with Ubuntu 18.04 and Java 8 from Oracle.
My Main class looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

My Mainifest looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

And its in the src folder. As well my /etc/environment.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

Lastly my /etc/profile

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

When I open my jar in the terminal:

```
Error Main class not found or not loaded
```

Finally I don't know where this stupid misstake is, maybe some can help me.

Comment: How do you run your jar file in the terminal? Is it through `java -jar` command?

Comment: Oneway with java -jar and the other round with java only

Comment: @muelleste Which files are inside the jar file?

Comment: @Progman what was key question. when I do "jar xf test.jar" only the meta packet was extract. So where is the .Java files :D. Got it! Thanks